# A question regarding conduct of war in Vedic age?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, war

Pranam,
I have heard that in Mahabharata times they used to destroy cities of enemies.. Hanuman burnt Lanka..and also Lord Indra is called Purandara..
But in past 2000 years we rarely find Hindu kings destroy conquered towns..
According to Vedic Religion there is only Sanatana Dharma(for Sanatanis)..Knowledge of
outside boundary of India was forbidden..
My question is when Indian kings(Like Yayati,Dilipa, Bharata)conquered the world did they burn cites of Non aryans?
Did they also destroy worship places of Foreigners(Since what they worship is not relevent to us)?
Kindly Quote references if possible..
*NO Hate to any religion